# Calculation of fuel

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table contains two fields named ME and STE with data type decimal.I want to find

(ME used for last 90 Days / Total STE for last 90 days) * 24

I need to solve this using sql. How can I write  query for solving this. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Anyone please help me to solve this. I am in trouble.

Comment: Does your table contain only two fields?What have you tried?

Comment: No a lot of fields are there. But I need these two fields for calculation @R.S

Comment: SELECT ME  FROM Table_name WHERE CreatedDate >= dateadd(d,-90,getdate())/(SELECT STE FROM Table_name WHERE CreatedDate >= dateadd(d,-90,getdate()))*24. This is what i tried but showing error as "Implicit conversion from data type datetime to decimal is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
" @R.S

Comment: Anyone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your formula as **(Total ME used for last 90 Days / Total STE for last 90 days) * 24** , i have written following query.

`select (SUM(ME)/SUM(STE))*24 AS cal from [YOUR TABLE NAME ] where ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE),[YOUR TABLE NAME ].CreatedDate))<=90`.

Let me know if it's working for you.

Comment: ITS FINE BUT IF I HAVE 10 ENTRIES ITS CALCULATING FAR OVERALL 10 ENTRIES. I NEED TO FIND OUT IT INDUVIDUALLY @R.S

Comment: then for each row , use select (ME/STE)*24 AS cal from [YOUR TABLE NAME ] where ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE),[YOUR TABLE NAME ].CreatedDate))<=90.